# The completeness of Spatial Schwarzschild manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

We know that the spatial Schwarzschild manifold is $\mathbb{R}^3/0$ with metric $g=(1+\frac{m}{2r})^4\delta$, where $\delta$ is the Euclidean matric.

Is there anyone know how to prove the completeness of the spatial Schwarzschild manifold?

Answer (score 2):

A sketch: you need to show that any geodesic can be extended indefinitely. For this, it is enough to show that all geodesics remain bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$; ie,   there are no solutions $\gamma:[0,t_0)\to \mathbb R^3\setminus 0$ to the  geodesic equations such that $\lim_{t\to t_0}\|\gamma(t)\|$ is either $0$ or $\infty$ (here $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm).

Next you take advantage of the symmetry of the metric and show that it is enough to show the above for *radial* geodesics, ie of the form $\gamma(t)=\gamma(0)r(t)$, for which the geodesic equations  reduce to   $r'=\pm f(r),$ where $f(r)= (1+\frac{m}{2r})^{-2}$.

Next  you show that to avoid a solution of $r'=f(r)$  going to $\infty$ and a solution of $r'=-f(r)$ going to $0$ as $t\to t_0$  it is enough to show that $f(r)$ and $r^2f(1/r)$ are bounded as $r\to\infty$.

These two properties are easy to verify for the given $f(r).$

I hope this argument makes snese and that you can fill-in the details.